Jest test passes correctly when test conditions are positive, but when conditions are negative, test hangs
This all started when I was trying to make a custom matcher. However, I later found out it was happening with built-in Jest matchers.
I have a test that subscribes to an observable and expects it to error. In the error handler of the observable I run my expects, one of which uses asymmetric matchers.
Here is a stackblitz of a minimal reproduction.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-3dywfk?file=src%2Ftest.ts
The basics is that I have
it('does something', (done) => {
  someObservable.subscribe({
    error: err => {
      expect(someJestFunc)
       .toHaveBeenCalledWith(
         expect.objectContaining({
           ...someOb,
           someProp: expect.myCustomMatcher(String) //though 
anything like expect.any(String) will also fail
         })
       );

      done();
    }
  });
});

And if the conditions are good, then the pass will test successfully. If the conditions fail, instead of printing the proper error messaging and failing the test normally, it will instead hang and only fail when it reaches the configured timeout for a test.
Not sure if this is a bug in my test or if I should report it to jest. But sure seems like I've done similar things in the past.
I've also attempted to use something like and this also does not work.
expect(someJestFunc.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual(<my asymmetric matchers from above)

